# Github Workflow / Action commit to repository returning 403

Tags: python, git, github, github-actions

I have a Github Workflow file where I bump the version of the python package (setup.py) and afterwards I want to push the changes to the repository the workflow runs in. But I get 403 no access granted back

```yaml
  build-package:
    permissions:
      contents: read
      id-token: write
      pull-requests: write
      issues: write
      repository-projects: write
      deployments: write
      packages: write
      

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: test
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      """ STEPS BETWEEN""""
      
      
      - name: Set up Python 3.10
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m pip install setuptools
          python -m pip install wheel
          python -m pip install bump
      - name: Bump version
        run: |
          bump --patch
          # add step that commits the setup.py and skips the ci/cd
      - name: Commit version
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git config --global user.name "bot"
          git commit -m "Bump version" setup.py
          git push

      - name: Build package
        run: |
          python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

It returns

```yaml
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/repository/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The git commit and push by itself is fine, you've just limited the scope of the GITHUB_TOKEN that is used for pushing to `read-only`.

Convert this:

```yaml
 permissions:
      contents: read
```

To this:

```yaml
 permissions:
      contents: write
```

Do be aware that this will only allow normal code changes to be pushed, and not for workflow files (those have extra security scopes).